# Update Panel hangs in ASP.NET with large gridview result

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

In my code I have an update panel that will hang with a large result.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" EnableViewState="false" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                            <div id="tablediv" style="width:1250px;height:100%;overflow:hidden;margin: 0px auto 0px auto;padding-top:35px;padding-bottom:15px;">

                                <div class="ScrollableDiv" style="max-height:100%;width:100%;overflow-y:auto;">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="gvResults"
                                        runat="server" 
                                        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="AlternateRow" RowStyle-CssClass="MainRow"
                                        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                        ShowHeader="false"
                                        DataKeyNames="pomOrdernum"
                                        CellPadding="0"
                                        CellSpacing="0"
                                        GridLines="None"
                                        >.... </asp:Gridview>
...
</ContentTemplate>
.... 
</UpdatePanel>
```

I have a asp:Button (it's hidden and clicked via javascript) that when pressed will go and sort the data and update the gridview with the sorted results. With larger data sets this will just hang. I have ellipses where there is more code

Answer (score 0):

I have found that when I try a post back that submits the view state outside of the update panel I get a "Request size is too large" error. I have found that it is submitting the viewstate that I use to keep track of the DataTable that is bound to the GridView and this view state element is too large for IIS. The easiest way to fix this is to increase the max request length in the web.config

```
   <system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="60"/>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="50000"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <!--<directoryBrowse enabled="true" showFlags="Date,Time,Extension,Size" />-->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="51200000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```